# Debugging in Java - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jboss7.x

i'm looking for solution to know if i'm in Debug mode or normal mode using Java when i'm starting eclipse. I'm using Jboss 7 like a server.

Exemple :

```
if (i'm starting eclipse with debug mode){
  //execution 1
}else{
  //execution 2
}
```